# Possible To Differentiate Between UK States - Google Maps JS API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to differentiate between Scotland, Wales, Northern Ireland and England when retrieving data via Google Maps, via the Javascript API or otherwise?

I have looked into a few examples in Google's docs, and it seems that Google does not give an option to differentiate between the different UK constituents.

The autocomplete examples for the JS API do have a return field 'STATE' but it is seems to only be used for US states and is returned null when querying a UK address. Google just returns 'United Kingdom' for the country when querying an address in the UK.

I need to get the country name back when I query Google Maps with a postcode.

EDIT/NOTE: if you give a city/town, only, in the query then Google DOES return the UK member state in the State field. But, Google is not returning the state when I search by postcode only, which is what I need.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: [This example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) straight from Google shows Ireland being returned as part of the address when I start typing in `10 Father Russell Rd`. Are you using a different form of auto-complete?

Comment: Hi. Yes, that's the same example I tried out. It returns 'Ireland' as 'Ireland' is not actually part of the UK. The UK is England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland and so it makes sense that Google may produce the result you got.

Comment: I have just tried typing in 'Glasgow' and it did return Scotland as the State....hmmm... I have just tried a couple other queries. It returns the UK State in the State field when I search by city/town, but not when I search by postcode which is annoying as I need to be able to do it by postcode.

Comment: I'm going to call it a day, for now, and just hard-code all Scottish postcodes into my website's code so that I can achieve what I need (charge different shipping rates for different parts of the UK), but I'll leave my question here.

Comment: Looks like my Geo-politics needs polishing! I can recreate the issue by typing in `G32` into that form... Hrm... Curious.

Comment: Could you do two requests?  First use the postcode to find out the city.  Then use the city to find out the 'state'.

Comment: @duncan that'll work-ish. It's just not 100% reliable/solid as more than one UK member state could each have a town/city with the same name. Even if, in the second query, I include both the city and postcode, Google again does not return the state (frustratingly!)